# Correct way to save PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser indentificator in database

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to save in database PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser indentificators for specific fields and that I call each field indentificators and use them as follows:

```
$query='select description from ........';
$result = .....;
//-this is how description is saved in the database
// $html->find('div.shortd',0)->outertext();
$row[0]=$html->find('div.shortd',0)->outertext();
$description = $row[0]; - this should be equivalent of:
$description = $html->find('div.shortd',0)->outertext();
```

but it doesn't work

What format should I save $html->find('div.shortd',0)->outertext(); so after I call it from database to make it work..

Let me explain you briefly what it will be used for:
Lets say I have 6000 suppliers. Each of them wish to upload products in my website. I made beta version of crawler which loads specific data from each supplier website so to successfully upload a product I just require the supplier to paste the url in his website of the product he wish to upload.
Each website has different structure and now I am facing a problem with this because the structure of each website very vary.
Lets say I wish to get img src of the product which may look like:

```
<div class="aa">
<p>text</p>
<p><img src="../url-to-image"></p>
</div>
```

so to get it I am doing this:

```
$image = $html->find('div.aa > p > img');
$image=$image->src;
```

This works if image is only 1 but to get all images I will have to loop trough images. So the only option for me is to save either:

```
$image = $html->find('div.aa > p > img');$image=$image->src;
```

in the database for single image website or similar code but including the loop code..
This is why I need to save it in database and than to load and make this php code working.. I hope now is more clear..

I tried with :

```
$description = eval($row[0]);
```

but it doesn't work also I can see in error log this:

```
syntax error, unexpected end of file in public_html/file.php: eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: it's useless. You can just save `div.shortd` as srgument for find in future

Comment: each time indntificator is different, sometimes will be outertext of div, but sometimes it will be last element from another div, sometimes will be the second child element of ul and so on.. That's why I want for each element to save the full indentificators code

Comment: the coorect identeficator is position of element in DOM (tree of html document). Internal identeficators of  an Parser object is useless because can vary every time while it building

Comment: Well looks like you don't understand the core of the issue. How you will find a src of image located in : <div class="aa"><p>text</p><p><img src="../url-to-image"></p></div>
--------------------------------- Please mind for the next product the img src will be located in totally different structure and so on for the next 6000 products..

Comment: Read 3 times, did not undestood why you dom't save link to image (src attribute)?

Comment: First of all I dont want to save the link, I am just using the link to download images.

Comment: I have a textarea in my database where I store the code, and then call the code with `eval($row["scrapecode"]);`.

Comment: Yes, actually I succeed with some little changes in database and eval() to read the php code, thank you Luke